# What is the purpose of jQuery's cleanData function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, memory-leaks, removechild

While studying the jQuery sourcecode I stumbled upon the `cleanData`-function several times:
jQuery.remove() calls it. So do other functions. What is the purpose of calling `cleanData` before removing the DOM-Element?

Is jQuery's `remove()`-method superior to a simple(removeChild) like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yU8xH/)?
And if so, why is it so? Does that code lead to memory leaks?

What is the data, which gets cleared before removal?
Is there any usecase outside jQuery?

Comment: Thank you for marking this question as a duplicate, especially, when the refered answer lacks of technical details, asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For elements that get event handlers, data, or perform certain other operations from jQuery methods, jQuery will create an entry in `jQuery.cache` for that element.

The element itself gets a property which holds the key to its entry in `jQuery.cache`. That's the only thing that links the element and the data.

So when an element is going to be removed, jQuery needs to look up the entry in `jQuery.cache` by using the key found on the element, and then needs to destroy the related data. If it didn't do this, there would be a memory leak since once the element is gone, there's no way to know that the `jQuery.cache` data should be removed.

So if you were to use the native `.removeChild()` to remove and destroy an element, you would be destroying the only link to that data. That's why you must unfortunately use jQuery for all element removal, and why you shouldn't use any other DOM libraries alongside jQuery.

Comment: So, if I am getting you right, there is no need for it outside of jQuery.

Comment: Yes. Generally, undocumented functions are that way for a reason.

Comment: @Lilith2k3: Yeah, there's no need to use it at all. It gets used internally when needed.